# Interwoven threads affecting linked list

Tags: c++, multithreading, thread-safety

I am told that the code in `insert()` isn't thread-safe because an interwoven thread can set `head` to `node` after another thread does, effectively loosing a link to one node. But no matter how many times I run this program I keep getting `2` as the number of nodes instead of `1`. Why is that?

```c++
#include <functional>
#include <iostream>
#include <thread>
#include <chrono>

struct List
{
    struct Node
    {
        int data{0};
        Node* next{0};
    };

    Node* head{0};

    void insert(int n)
    {
        Node* node = new Node{n};
        node->next = head;
        head = node;
    }
};

int Count(List& list)
{
    int count = 0;
    for (List::Node* head = list.head; head != nullptr; head = head->next)
        count++;
    return count;
}

int main()
{
    List i;
    std::thread t1(&List::insert, &i, 5);
    std::thread t2(&List::insert, &i, 3);
    t1.join();
    t2.join();
    std::cout << Count(i);
}
```

<kbd>[Demo](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/be2c831dd646ce4b)</kbd>

Comment: Your threads are probably not running long enough to conflict. That is, the first thread is probably already finished before the second thread even starts. Create a function that adds 100 (or 1000) nodes and call that in each thread.

Comment: The window for the race condition is tiny - both threads would have to run a few critical instructions in `insert` at exactly the same time to see it. That's almost certainly not going to happen if each thread just does that once - the first thread probably does it before the second starts. Try adding millions of nodes from each thread, and see if any go missing.

Comment: @MikeSeymour You guys are right. When I insert a million times I get the "expected" results -- http://melpon.org/wandbox/permlink/APJl7shKbSVyREf1

Comment: @MikeSeymour I know this is an off-topic question, but why do people use `sleep_for()` inside threads?

Comment: @templateboy: To make the the thread stop working for a while.

Comment: @MikeSeymour Changing `Node* node = new Node{n}` to `Node* node = new Node{n, head}` [doesn't solve the problem](http://melpon.org/wandbox/permlink/BtJttabWYxzpremd), but I thought making it a single operation *would*.

Comment: @templateboy: No, you need `node->next = head; head = node;` to be an atomic operation, for which you need either a mutex, or some more complicated lock-free logic.

Comment: @MikeSeymour So putting a lock above `new Node{n, head}` is correct?

Comment: @templateboy: Or afterwards: it's access to `head` that you need to guard.

Comment: @MikeSeymour But doesn't it *have* to be above `new Node{n, head}` since that code is using `head`?